# Hash Table Insertion Time Complexity Confusion

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, hashtable

I understand that insertion for hash tables is O(1) and sometimes O(n) depending on the load factor. This makes sense to me, however, I'm still confused. When talking about insertion, are we including the hash function in that measurement or is it just placing some value at that index? For ints, I could see how it could be O(1), but what about strings or any other objects?

**Edit:** This seemed to answer my question, sorry about the confusion.
[Time complexity of creating hash value of a string in hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549669/time-complexity-of-creating-hash-value-of-a-string-in-hashtable/31555165#31555165)

Comment: The hash function should be `O(1)`. It shouldn't scale with the input. Hence can be ignored for insertion.

Comment: That's what I thought @VLAZ but rici has a different opinion but idk which one to believe.

Comment: A hashing function used for a hash table should be fast because if it's not, it's not really worth using a hash table if storing and retrieving values is going to be linear time. It's the same as a list, in that case. It's quite reasonable to assume `O(1)` hashing for a well-designed hash table. It's quite probably for a hash to achieve that: [Complexity of Hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6873039). The implementation should probably be tuned to the volume of data you expect but that's also expressed as the load factor anyway.

Comment: @vlaz: Suppose you have a small hash table with huge keys, say resource URIs. How do you avoid the length of the keys affecting the hash computation? That's not related to the occupancy of the table; it's orthogonal.

Comment: @rici As I said, hash function may need to be tuned. There is no need for a perfect hash function over strings of unbound length. Such a thing cannot exist. However, a function that is *unlikely* to produce hashes *over a known type of input* is not impossible. You still have to compute a hash that is distributed *evenly enough* through different hash buckets. If you know you have 100 items coming in or 1000 and you know the general shape you can endure, say, 1% collision rate. If you mean to say that it's *impossible* to create such a hash function I'd be disappointed with the CompSci field.

Comment: @VLAZ  Can we point to some standard or something that provides a more straightforward answer to this? I'm still confused. While I understand that a good hashing algorithm should try and get O(1), it depends on the data involved, so it just can't be O(1) for all data types.

Comment: @vlaz: I don't see why anyone would think that my failings in any way reflect "the CompSci field", which I certainly don't in any way represent. But anyway, I gave an example of how to modify a hash function in my answer, but like any algorithm which ignores a large part of the key, it makes it trivial for an attacker to craft an arbitrary number of different keys with the same hash, thus opening the door to a DoS attack. In any case, it doesn't help asymptotic complexity, because of other O(|key|) computations: comparing the key to the one you found, and copying the key into the table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the hash function needs to be included in the cost of lookup in a hash table, just the like comparison function needs to be included in the cost of lookup in a sorted table. If the keys have unbounded size, then the key length must be somehow accounted for.

You could stop computing the hash at a certain fixed key length. (Lua does that, for example). But there is a pathological case where every new key is a suffix of the previously inserted key, which would eventually reduce a bounded-length hash function to a linear search.

Regardless of the hash function, the hash table lookup must eventually compare the found key --if there is one-- with the target key, to ensure that they are the same. So that must take time proportional to the size of the key.

In short, constant average-time hash table lookup requires that keys have a bounded size, which is not necessarily the case. But since alternative lookup algorithms would also be affected by key size, this fact doesn't generally help in comparing different lookup up algorithms.

Comment: @VLAZ has a different opinion so idk which one to believe Edit: I have always believed that we do not include the hash function.

Comment: True, you could stop at a certain length, but that doesn't mean it's O(1). How would this work for strings? It would have to be some O(n) where n is the length of the string in this case. You will need to go through each index and compute some unique hash for each character.

Comment: @sam_i_am: Cormen (p. 227) says "We *assume* that the hash value h(k) can be computed in O(1) time." That's not the same as saying "we don't count the computation of h(k)". Similarly, the complexity of binary search is usually cited with the assumption that you can compare keys in O(1), even though that's clearly not the case if the keys have unbounded size. But it simplifies the analysis.

Comment: @sam_i_am: You compute the hash from a fixed number of characters. For example, you chould just hash the first 64 characters of long strings. Or you could use a more sophisticated algorithm; IIRC, Lua divides the total length of the string by some constant like 32 to get a skip amount, which is uses to skip through the string so that it compares the 32 characters at positions 0, k, 2k, ..., 31k. (That avoids the suffix problem I noted in my example.) Stochastic fixed-size hashing *usually works*, but it's open to DoS attacks if you care about those.

Comment: In any case, as I said in the answer, eventually you need to verify that the looked up key matches, for which there are no shortcuts; you must compare the full key. That would only be unnecessary on average if you never practically never found a false positive, which would only be possible if you were certain in advance that the new key is not in the table. In some cases, that's true (rehashing, for example), but in general, it probably isn't.

Comment: Even if I did hash just the first 64 characters, how's is that O(1)? I agree with VLAZ that the hash function has to be fine-tuned, but still idk how O(1) is even a possibility.

Comment: @sam_i_am: O(1) means constant time. 64 is a constant. In general constant factors don't count in Big-O notation; O(3n²+8) and O(n²) are the same set of functions.

Comment: yes, that is possible, but that's for that specific algorithm. What about others who compute their hash in O(n) time? I found this article explaining it more. @rici https://stackoverflow.com/a/31555165/16846267

Comment: @sam_i_am: i think i have been clear from the beginning that the time complexity of hash table insertion with non scalar keys has to account for the size of the key. While it is theoretically and practically possible to limit hash computation to constant time, that does not remove the cost of handling the key and it is not necessarily desirable. I think I've said all that two or three times now, so I won't repeat it again. If I haven't been clear, I apologise. You can accept this answer or not, as you choose.

Comment: Then that is my bad then, as I failed to understand your comments, and maybe my question was phrased poorly from the start.